# php split / cluster binary into chunks based on next 1 in cycle

Tags: php, split, binary, chunking

I need to figure out a method using PHP to chunk the 1's and 0's into sections.

```
1001 would look like: array(100,1)


1001110110010011 would look like: array(100,1,1,10,1,100,100,1,1)
```

It gets different when the sequence starts with 0's... I would like it to segment the first 0's into their own blocks until the first 1 is reached)

```
00110110 would look like (0,0,1,10,1,10)
```

How would this be done with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) to split your string, using the following regex:

```
10*|0
```

This matches either a `1` followed by some number of `0`s, or a `0`. Since a regex always tries to match the parts of an alternation in the order they occur, the second part will only match `0`s that are not preceded by a `1`, that is those at the start of the string. PHP usage:

```
$beatstr = '1001110110010011';
preg_match_all('/10*|0/', $beatstr, $m);
print_r($m);
$beatstr = '00110110';
preg_match_all('/10*|0/', $beatstr, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 100
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 10
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/E9WvQ)

Comment: @Jeff not sure if you saw my edit, I've simplified the regex.